# TypeScript error TS1005: '?' expected. in decorator function

Tags: typescript

I have decorator `sequelizeModel` for my class `Account` but when I try to compile TS code to JS I get this error:
`src/models/Account.ts(3,93): error TS1005: '?' expected.`

Error points to decorator function definition `<Account extends Model>(target: Account extends Model)`

Code:

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const sequelizeModel: ClassDecorator = <Account extends Model>(target: Account extends Model) => {
    return target;
}

const column = function (options: any) {
    return function (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol): void {
        Reflect.defineMetadata('model:column', {[propertyKey]: options}, target)
    }
}

@sequelizeModel
export class Account extends Model<Account, Partial<Account>> {
    @column({
        field: 'uuid',
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    })
    uuid: string;

    @column({
        field: 'account_name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
    })
    accountName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extends` portion should only be inside the `<>`s:

```
const sequelizeModel: ClassDecorator = <Account extends Model>(target: Account) => {
```